# Can Travis CI generate a badge for a specific Matrix configuration?

Tags: travis-ci

I am testing my library against two different versions of my SDK: the stable SDK and the dev SDK. Specifically: https://travis-ci.org/google/serialization.dart

I expect my library to pass its tests with the stable SDK. However, the tests might fail with the dev SDK because the dev SDK might be broken.

I'd like to display two badges to my users, to clearly indicate that "yes, the build failed, but it was just the dev SDK".

Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This open source web app can create badges for a matrix build:
https://github.com/bjfish/travis-matrix-badges

Comment: Works but the output isn't very user friendly

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it looks like the answer is No: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/1809

Answer (score 0):

Now you can, by using the https://github.com/exogen/badge-matrix. Make sure you use `env=BADGE={configuration}` as a query param and also inside Travis Matrix add

```
env:
   BADGE={configuration}
```