# Is it possible to run 2 seperate .travis.yml files from the same github repository

Tags: python, travis-ci, pep8

My current use case is that I use travis-ci very happily to run my test cases for a python project.  This reports a fail or pass based on whether the py.unit tests pass.

I would like to add pep8 checking to this repository as well, but I don't want my core functionality tests to fail if there is some incorrectly formatted code, but I would like to know about it.

Any possible ways of dealing with this would be useful, but my immediate thought was, is there any way of having 2 separate test runners, running off the same repository? ".travis.yml" running the main tests, and a separate process monitoring my pep8 compliance from ".travis2.yml" for example.

I would then have 2 jobs running, and could see if my core functionality tests are still OK at a glance(from the github badge for example), but also how my pep8 compliance is going.

Thanks

Mark

Comment: So it turns out that there is a service for doing pep8 checks and others for github python repos called landscape.io

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/ :

> Travis CI uses .travis.yml file in the root of your repository to
>   learn about your project and how you want your builds to be executed.

A mixture of `matrix` and `allow_failures`could be used in the single .travis.yml file to address your use case of having two jobs run where one build reports your functionality tests and a second build gives you feedback on your pep8 compliance,

For example, the following .travis.yml file cause two builds to occur on traivs.  In only one of the builds (i.e. where `PEP=true`), the pep8 check would occur. If the pep8-check failed it wouldn't be considered a failure due to `allow_failures`:

```
language: python

env:
  - PEP=true
  - PEP=false
matrix:
  allow_failures:
    - env: PEP=true
script:
  - if $PEP ; then pep8 ; fi
  - python -m unittest discover
```

Comment: Thanks very much @nfranklin.  I have updated the code to do this and it works very nicely.  The only slight annoyance is that there isn't a very good way of displaying the matrix job in my github readme.md but im sure this will come one day.
The only addition I made was to put the unit test runner in the else statement, and as there is some big setup steps, I also wrapped up the install step with if statements. [my .travis.yml](https://github.com/DiamondLightSource/Savu/blob/master/.travis.yml)

Comment: Related to your problem on displaying the matrix job on your github readme.md, I found this related question: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25903891/can-travis-ci-generate-a-badge-for-a-specific-matrix-configuration).  The suggested web app seems to be helpful, I tried it out with your repo using the following link:  https://travis-matrix-badges.herokuapp.com/repos/DiamondLightSource/Savu/branches/master